# React native - Android Native module : How to send a view from javascript to java

Tags: react-native

I tried to create a new native module to show a toast. It worked. 
So I tried to add a snackbar. But as you know snackbar needs a view as first argument ( Snackbar.make(view, message, duration) ).

How do I supply view from react native to Java. I am stuck here.

Below is how I call the toast successfully (RNToastMessage.show).

```
onButtonPress = () => {
  const { email, pass } = this.state;
  const { RNToastMessage } = NativeModules;
  this.setState({ error: '' })
  RNToastMessage.show("Hola!", RNToastMessage.SHORT); // This works
  RNToastMessage.showSnack(WhatToDoHere, "Hola!!", RNToastMessage.SHORT); // How to implement this?
}
```